# ¿Qué error me puede estar dando al mapear la base de datos?

Tags: java, mvc, web, spring

La `bd` está en un `docker`, el archivo `properties` está bien a menos que falte algo, los campos de la entidad están bien también, el proyecto en ningún momento me da un error pero no me devuelve ningún valor y en la `bd` sí los hay.

```
@Controller
public class AsignaturaController {

   @Autowired
   private AsignaturaRepository repo;

   @GetMapping("/")
   public String devuelveAsignaturas(Model model){
      List<Asignatura> asignaturaList = repo.findAll();
      System.out.println(asignaturaList.size());
      model.addAttribute("Asignaturas",asignaturaList);
      return "index";
   }
```

Añado la entidad Asignaturas

```
   @Entity
   @Table(name="Asignaturas")
   @Getter
   @Setter
   public class Asignatura {
      @Id
      @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
      private Long id;

      @Column(name = "nombre")
      private String nombre;

      @Column(name = "descripcion")
      private String descripcion;
   }
```

El repositorio:

```
@Repository
public interface AsignaturaRepository extends JpaRepository<Asignatura, Long> {
    }
application.properties:
    properties:
    spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/InstitutoMontecastelo
    spring.datasource.username=root
    spring.datasource.password=abc123.
    # Configuración del proveedor JPA (Hibernate)
    #spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
    spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a stackoverflow en español. Con sólo lo detallado es algo difícil poder brindarte ayuda. El artículo [Cómo hacer una pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) puede serte de utilidad para editar tu post. Si es posible brindar un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) en donde agregues mensajes de log o alguna otra cosa que estés haciendo mostrando detalles de cómo se comporta y cuál es el resultado